# Relative imports do not work from imported modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a program that is laid out like the following:

```
test\test.py
test\modules\base.py
test\modules\blah.py
```

I need to load modules by name. Each module implements a class with the same methods, so I load them into a dictionary so that I can reference them as needed. I'm getting the follow error trying to do a relative import.

```
  File "modules/blah.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseModule
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there a way to use relative imports from code imported using importlib?
I'm using Python 3. The following is a simple example showing this error...

test\test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import importlib
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("blah", "modules/blah.py")
        mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
def main():
    t = Test()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test\modules\base.py:

```
class BaseModule():
    modulename = "base"
    def __init__(self,name):
        print("Initializing module %s" % (self.modulename))
```

test\modules\blah.py:

```
from .base import BaseModule
class BlahModule(BaseModule):
    modulename = "blah"
```

Comment: https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent/

Comment: @Leonid I don't understand the napuzba.com page.  There are references throughout to a demos (/toplevel/project/demos/demo.py) folder that is not shown in the file system, and there is no explanation of where demos came from.  The directory seems to be named package, but they refer to it as demos.  How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code should help:

```
import os
import sys


module_path = "modules/blah.py"
module_dir = os.path.dirname(module_path)
if module_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_dir)
# do actual import of module here
```